# Is a digital signature of use if you don't also encrypt the message containing it?

Tags: public-key, signature

I'm *sure* this has been asked before. Its just too blindingly obvious.

from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)

"Digital signatures, in which a message is signed with the sender's private key and can be verified by anyone who has access to the sender's public key."

So lets say Bob sends Alice an unencrypted message, and Charlie overhears it. What's to stop Charlie from signing his own messages with that private key and  henceforth having the ability to impersonate Bob?

So is there a point to digitally signing some message that isn't also encrypted? Or are all communications using digital signatures also encrypted? Wikipedia made it seem like there were two independent ideas, but I can't see a use case for signing-without-encrypting, where I can for encrypting-without-signing and encrypting-and-signing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So lets say Bob sends Alice an unencrypted message, and Charlie overhears it. What's to stop Charlie from signing his own messages with that private key and henceforth having the ability to impersonate Bob?

Alice already possesses Bob's public key $\text{pub}_{B}$, and Bob is the only one that has access to the corresponding private key, $\text{priv}_{B}$.

The private key is not shared with anyone, while the public key can be published.

Bob can use $\text{priv}_{B}$ to perform the sign procedure which creates a signature $s$ from a message $m$.

Then Alice acquires $s, m$ and can use them with $\text{pub}_{B}$ to perform the verify procedure, which only outputs $1$ if $s$ was created using $m, \text{priv}_{B}$.

Charlie does not have $\text{priv}_{Bob}$, and so he cannot create a value $s$ for any $m$ that will pass the verify procedure that Alice will perform. (At least, he cannot do so with non-negligible probability, assuming that the signature scheme is secure).

> So is there a point to digitally signing some message that isn't also encrypted?

Yes

> Or are all communications using digital signatures also encrypted?

No

> Wikipedia made it seem like there were two independent ideas

They are two independent ideas.

Digital signatures provide authenticity and integrity of the signed message - if the signature verifies correctly, then you know that the message came from Bob and was not tampered with.

Encryption provides confidentiality, which means that unauthorized parties cannot learn the contents of the message.

> but I can't see a use case for signing-without-encrypting, where I can for encrypting-without-signing and encrypting-and-signing.

There are plenty of use cases for signatures without encryption.

Exchanging public keys for public-key encryption or key agreement is one of the most important examples (e.g. [Public key Infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure)).

Comment: @user1733212 In the example above, $m$ is an arbitrary string of bits and so it does not matter if it is a plaintext or ciphertext. $s$ is *not* an encryption of $m$, many sources falsely claim that digital signatures are "encrypting with the private key and decrypting with the public key", which is only even vaguely close to true for RSA, and not even close to true with basically all other signature schemes ever. A signature is not an encrypted message, remember from the definition above that encryption preserves confidentiality and both $s, m$ are public knowledge.

Comment: Sorry, I clicked submit before I finished. Not sure what you think I think. This is what I meant to type after your first post ...................................ok. So the key itself is not included... rather, a piece of the message that has a pre-established text is encrypted with the private key, and if you can decrypt it to that pre-established text using the public key of the person who claims to have sent it, then you know the message is legit.

Comment: Here's a followup.... how does it verify message integrity? If my message gets changed in transit, either because charlie is a jerk, or because my wire got zapped by some cosmic radiation, that wouldn't be defended against in my scheme. Is there something like a checksum also embedded in the signature?

Comment: @user1733212 As stated in my comment to you, "encrypted with the private key" and "decrypted with the public key" is not at all accurate, a signature is something wholly and completely different. For example, you can construct signatures based off of Diffie-Hellman, which is not public-key encryption. There is no pre-established text included either, the answer above outlines what information needs to be pre-established and what can be sent over the wire. 1/2

Comment: 2/2: The specifics of how the verification routine works are particular to the signature scheme that is being used (of which there are many). Remember (from the answer) that the verify routine outputs $1$ if and only if $\text{pub}_{B}, m, s$ are supplied as inputs to the routine. If $m$ is modified, then the value supplied to the verify routine is no longer $m$ but $m'$ - some other $m$, and hence the verify procedure will not output $1$ when supplied $\text{pub}_{B}, m', s$. The signature is a "checksum" of sorts, albeit a cryptographic one.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time--------
so Bob has 2 functions, "encrypt" and "sign". Both take a message. "Encrypt" takes alice's public key and returns ciphertext. This is a lossless, reversible transformation IFF you have alice's private key (and presumably bob's "decrypt" function, which is also public?).  "Sign" takes Bob's private key and returns a signature. This is an extremely lossy transformation (but who cares). Holder's of Bob's public key can use that and the signature with Bob's "de-sign" function to get the value 1, a pre-established "message".-------
Any better?

Comment: @user1733212 For your encrypt example: The decryption function is known by both of them, indeed it is known by all parties. Signatures are not necessarily a lossy transformation, though in practice they frequently will be due to a hash of the message being signed rather than the message itself. Holders of Bob's public key can use it, the message, and the signature with a publicly known "verify" function, which outputs 1iff the signature was created on the message using Bob's private key. The encrypt/decrypt/sign/verify algorithms are all public information, and do not belong to any one party.